# Using and/or operators in assigning values to streamline code (lua)

Tags: lua

I'd like to ask if it's possible to streamline this example snippet of code:

```
local left = true
local right = true

local xPos = 0

if left or right then
    if left and not right then
        xPos = -1
    elseif right and not left then
        xPos = 1
    else
        xPos = 0
    end
end
```

(Returns -1 when left == true, 1 when right == true, 0 if either are true or false)

using and/or operators when declaring the value itself, like so:

```
local left = true
local right = true

local xPos = right and not left and 1 or -1
```

The issue with the latter example is it doesn't behave like the former one, as it returns -1 when both are true or false.

If someone were to explain how the latter declaration of xPos works in detail that'd be much appreciated as well, thank you.

Comment: Try this `local xPos = (right ~= left) and (right and 1 or -1) or 0`.
Maybe there is a smoother solution.

Comment: Works fine! I'm still a little confused on the `(right and 1 or -1)` part, though. How does the engine know which value to pick from the given 1 or -1?

Comment: It's a bit difficult for me to describe that.
This would be the same expression ((right and 1) or (-1)). `and` has a higher precedence than `or`. So if `right == true` then `true and 1`, this expression evaluates to `1` (a true value) -> the `or` is fullfilled.
If `right == false` then `false and 1` evaluates to false -> `false or -1` evaluates to -1 (a true value).
I hope that answers your question.

Comment: It did answer my question, I understand now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way lua handles ternary operators is it assigns the last variable evaluated.

Your code as an example:

```
local xPos = right and not left and 1 or -1
```

`right and not left` when this evaluates `true` then your section looks like:

```
local xPos = true and 1 or -1
```

because the `and` statement's first value is `true` the `and` statement returns second value in the comparison `1` the `or` statement then never evaluates the `-1` as a result because `1` is a "truthy" value, so the last variable evaluated was `1`and this is what `xPos` is set to.

If you make a change to the code you can see how this works from another angle.

```
local xPos = false and 1
```

What happens here? `xPos = false`. this is because when using an `and` lua will not continue the evaluation if the first condition is `false`. This means the last variable evaluated was `false` so `xPos = false`.

Comment: "the or statement is never evaluated as a result" that's literally wrong! the `or` returns 1 as result (`(right and not left and 1) or -1`)

Comment: true i will correct that, i meant value `-1` was not evaluated